# pisdk php when get values use ArcValue

Tags: php, dll, com, osisoft

When I use `$point->Data()->ArcValue(strtotime("now"),rtAuto,null);` I get below error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: 
> Parameter 0: Type mismatch.in
> C:\index3.php:58 Stack trace: #0 C:\index3.php(58):
> variant->ArcValue(1625754415, 5, NULL)
> #1 {main}thrown in  C:\index3.php on line 58

How can I use the function ArcValue?

Comment: The correct tag for OSIsoft PI products is 'osisoft' - have corrected this for you. I haven't used pisdk with php, but I'd guess 1) make sure that ArcValue is being called against the PIPoint object, so it knows where to look for the data. Perhaps the `->Data()` is unnecessary? 2) Check that the strtotime() is returning the time in the format that the function expects it. Check what kind of class ArcValue() expects to receive the time in.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the time stamp is wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).